Phone number verification components on Android phone
I have a question regarding a specific Canadian law process. I'm developing an app that will be available for users in Canada. The app supports two languages: English and French. During the phone number verification process, if the app is set to English, users receive the Android system component (bottom sheet) with the verification code in English. However, if the app is set to French, users still receive this message in English.
My client mentioned that, according to Canadian law, the message must be in French if the app is set to French. I'm unsure how to change this, as it is an Android system component.
Any advice or guidance on how to ensure compliance with this requirement would be greatly appreciated.
I tried to find an answer in another group and looked for it on the internet.
